# TypeError: window.open is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I keep getting this error on firebug -> TypeError: window.open is not a function

code:

```
    $(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.div').click(function()
    {
        var link = $(this).data('link');
        window.open(link);
    });
});
```

Isn't that function supposed to work?

Comment: Have you overridden `open` in the previous code?

Comment: what is the .div link attribute..?

Comment: @teemu - no, i haven't

Comment: @dipesh - data-link="http://<?php echo $fav['favLink']; ?>", and when I alert(link) it shows the link properly.

Comment: and I try just window.open("www.google.com") and it still don't work

Comment: Hmm... this really doesn't make sense. Can you provide an "non-working" example at [jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Try `console.log(window.open)` on the "not working page" to see what happened.

Comment: Please let me know which browser you are using(Just for the information) Also can you please try window.open("http://google.com"); instead of window.open(link); Just to test if url is creating any issue.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wyjmG/1/

Comment: Try [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wyjmG/2/); you were missing jQuery.

Comment: doesn't work neither. Tried it on chrome, firefox and IE

Comment: @jack - it works. but why isn't working on my page? what can mess with window.open to get that kind of error?

Comment: You can find out what messed with `window.open` by doing `console.log(window.open)`; other code could do something like `window.open = false;`

Answer (score 15):

late but for all other coders! if you have a global variable named "open" like "open = true;" or "var open = true" or something like that, then the function "open()" would not work anymore.

Comment: yeah I had a code like this:
var open = window.open(l.attr("href"), l.attr("target"));
if (open == null || typeof(open)=='undefined') {document.location = l.attr("href");}
had to change "open" var name to "wOpen"

Comment: Is there a way to reset this open variable to default js function?

Comment: @SubjectX No, you only have to remove the "open" variable or rename it. I think renaming would be very easy task.

Answer (score 2):

Although it's not entirely clear from your question, the value of `window.open` is not read-only and can therefore be changed by other code, such as:

```
window.open = false;
// ...
window.open('something') // error: window.open is not a function
```

If you know what scripts are loaded on your page, this shouldn't be hard to do, just search for anything relating to `window.open`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
window.open("https://www.google.com/", "_blank");
```

This code is working fine for me. If this doesn't work then make sure you should not declare a variable or function named with "open". (I have faced this issue once.)

Comment: Thank you, I have the same problem and have no idea that the variable could affect the function open()

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why but below change works for me in your fiddle.

Change

```
var link = $(this).attr('data-link');
window.open(link);
```

Comment: this is weird. can something be messing with window.open? what?

Comment: @user2084627 even i don't know what is wrong but i tried above and its worked...may be conflicting with html5 i guess...

Answer (score 0):

If you tried it in chrome console and found it not working, try it as a script preloaded with the page. It worked in my case.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a local variable named "window" or "open" then the function "window.open()" would not work anymore.